# cy.wrap().its()... doesn't work when the value in .its() contains a period

Tags: javascript, cypress, special-characters, cypress-custom-commands

I am looking to extract a URL parameter from the current URL I'm testing with Cypress. I was able to basically get the answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984643/185967), however, my extracted values are not available to me when I use Cypress's [.its() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its).
The parameters in the url all have periods in them, and I believe this is the cause for my error.
Here is my custom Cypress Command I'm building:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getParmsCommand', function(value) {
cy.url().as('url')

cy.then( () => {
  cy.log(this.url)
  const kvPairArray = this.url.toString().split('?')[1].toString().split('&')
  const paramObj = {}
  kvPairArray.forEach(param => {
    cy.log(param)
    //default 'value' to 0 if it doesn't exist
    const [ key, value="0" ] = param.split('=')
    paramObj[key] = value
  })
  //forcefully adding a debug element to the key value store for testing
  paramObj['beverage'] = 'soda'

cy.wrap(paramObj)
  .its('timeline.ws')                                   //doesn't work
  // .its(`${Cypress.$.escapeSelector('timeline.ws')}`) doesn't work
  // .its('timeline\.ws')                               doesn't work
  // .its('"timeline.ws"')                              doesn't work
  // .its('beverage')                                   this DOES work!
  .then(parmVal => {
    cy.log(parmVal)
})
```

Here is the relevant part of the URL that I'm trying to extract from:

> timeline.ws=3600000&timeline.to&timeline.fm&timeline.ar=false

You can see from the error that Cypress is only looking for the id *timeline*, NOT *timeline.ws*; it completely ignores everything after the period, and thus, never finds my parameter.
[image: Cypress error message]

I saw there was a [similar error with Cypress's .get()](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2027#issuecomment-400091361) function back in 2018.

Comment: Have you console.log your `paramObj` to check it is working correctly?

Comment: Is there a need to use the object in that way? Could you not just wrap `paramObj['timeline.ws']`?

Comment: BTW take a look at [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) as an alternative `paramObj` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.its()` is just a shorthand for property extraction. Since it fails with the period, you could instead use bracket notation in a `.then()`.

```js
cy.wrap(paramObj)
  .then(paramObj => paramObj['timeline.ws'])
```

or just

```js
cy.wrap(paramObj['timeline.ws'])
```

---

Playing around with the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor

```js
const urlString = 'http://example.com?timeline.ws=3600000&timeline.to&timeline.fm&timeline.ar=false'
const url = new URL(urlString)

cy.wrap(url.searchParams.get('timeline.ws'))
  .should('eq', '3600000')

cy.wrap(url.searchParams.get('timeline.to'))
  .should('be.empty')

cy.wrap(url.searchParams.get('timeline.ar'))
  .should('eq', 'false')
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you @TesterDick for the in depth answer. Referencing the paramObj['timeline.ws'] is the route I'm going. Works exactly as I need it to.